# Time frame of these sentences

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, future-tense, sequence-of-tenses

The tenses are divided into 12 main categories depending on their time frame i.e. Present, Past and Future.

I want to know then under which time frame these sentences can be categorised.

> *It could not have snowed on 25th of September.*

> *It would have been a disaster without your help.*

> *It should have outperformed the other tests.*

Under which type we can keep these sentences? There can be many other variations but basically I want to know how we can know their time frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It could not have snowed on 25th of September.

This is a statement about the past.

> It would have been a disaster without your help.

This is also a statement about the past.  Things passed off without a disaster, thanks to your help.

> It should have outperformed the other tests.

This, too, is a statement about the past.  The tests have already taken place.  "It" has already taken place.